# Clickable div with fixed width and height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a problem with one menu's element. I want to turn it to clickable `div`.

I tried this:

```
 <div id="nav-user" class="nav-menu-icon float-left">
  <a  href=".." class="nav-sprite ns-user" ></a>
</div>
```

But `a` and `div` elements are using `background-position`, `fixed-width` and `height` (I can't use 100% for `width` and `height` here). So, is it possible to make a clickable `div`?

```
.ns-user {
    width: 13px;
    height: 14px;
    background-position: 0px -419px;

}

 #nav-user.active .ns-user {
    width: 13px;
    height: 14px;
    background-position: 0px -419px;

}

#nav-user:hover .ns-user {
    width: 13px;
    height: 14px;
    background-position: 0px -419px;

}
```

Comment: can you put it in a jsfiddle?

Comment: If you want to make the div clickable, you have to wrap the a tag around the div tag.

Answer (score 0):

Since the anchor tag is an inline element, change it to block to allow it to get explicit height and width values.  That should get it to fill the parent.

```
.ns-user {
    display:block;
}
```